# Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $2⌊x⌋ ≤ ⌊2x⌋ ≤ 2⌊x⌋+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So far I got the below and is unsure where to go from there...

By definition, $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor =m$ such that

$$m\leq x< m+1\text{ }\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\wedge \forall m\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\iff m+n\leq x+n<m+n+1\text{ }\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\therefore\left\lfloor x+n\right\rfloor = m+n=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+n$$
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\in\mathbb{Z}:\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\leq x < \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+1$$

---

Edit after receiving hints:

Let $⌊x⌋=m$ with $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then there exists $\varepsilon \in [0,1)$ such that $x=m+\varepsilon$.
Thus, we have: $2⌊x⌋=2m ≤ ⌊2x⌋=⌊2m+2\varepsilon⌋=2m+⌊2\varepsilon⌋$, which proves the first inequality.

2⌊x⌋+1= 2m+1, and ⌊2ε⌋≤1 for ε∈[0,1).
Thus,⌊2x⌋= 2m+⌊2ε⌋≤2⌊x⌋+1= 2m+1, which proves the second inequality.

Comment: Have you tried writing $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + y$ for  some $y \in [0,1)$?

Comment: Also, "\$\lfloor x \rfloor\$" gives $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: Let ⌊x⌋=m with m∈Z. Then there exists ϵ∈[0,1) such that x=m+ϵ.Thus, we have: 2⌊x⌋=2m ≤ ⌊2x⌋=⌊2m+2ϵ⌋.This proves the first inequality right?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: you can get integers out of the floor function $\lfloor 2m+2\epsilon\rfloor=2m+\lfloor 2\epsilon\rfloor$. Now which interval does $2\epsilon$ belongs to ?

Comment: @A.E.Rosas That edit looks like to be on top of old revision of the post (OP changed the content in between)

Comment: @Sil I didn't notice that! Is it possible to revert my changes?

Comment: @A.E.Rosas I did rollback for you, feel free to do any additional udpate on current revision

Comment: @Sil thanks for catching that!

Comment: I think it is better to let full history in this case, I edited accordingly, to show that OP actually made efforts after receiving hints.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $\lfloor 2m+2\varepsilon\rfloor=2m+\lfloor2\varepsilon\rfloor$. What values can $\lfloor2\varepsilon\rfloor$ take?